# Is it possible to change language/culture info only for a given application? / WinPhone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, multilingual

Is it possible to change language/culture info only for a given application? The desired behavior is to let users choose which language they like to use in my app, without changing the language of the device/phone. Also, it must be a run-time feature (i.e. the user chooses the language and the app switches to the language at the same time). Is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: use Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("es"); 
If "es" is not supported, use another unused culture to fake it

Comment: Hi entropy. Thanks for the comment. I'm already using Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, but I guess that I don't know where to put this code. I've tried to put it at App.cs and before InitializeComponents of views, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you will have to manually set the localization behavior for the app. Check for more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Specifically, you will have to re-work the bindings to be attached to locally managed values that are being changed based on application and not system-wide settings.

Comment: Hi Den, thanks for the infos. I've already checked this link before. But I'm not sussceeding to change labels at runtime. Can you put an example/codesample to show how the mechams is?